# Prove by induction, multiplication sequence

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

i am struggling with this multiplication sequence proof.

Problem: Prove by induction that:

$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (3 -  \frac{3}{i^2})$ = $\frac{3(n+1)}{2n}$

This is my attempt or what I am thinking:

$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (3 -  \frac{3}{i^2})$ is basically -> $3 -$ $\frac{3}{n^2}$

So then P(n) should become: $3 -$ $\frac{3}{n^2}$ = $\frac{3(n+1)}{2n}$

But then i get an issue with step 1.

So step1: Show that P(1) is true

What i get is: $3 - 3 = \frac{3(2)}{2}$
Which is: $0 = 3$ Which is false..

What am i doing wrong and how should i proceed to prove this?? I tried writing out the sequence, but then the multipilication begins with $0 * \frac{9}{4} * ... *   (3 -\frac{3}{n^2})$ . Maybe i am mixing stuff up with the addition sequences??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the product is always zero as written. On the other hand, if you start from $i=2$ all is well.

Comment: In this context, since I am give i = 1 to start with, i should just give a counter example and i am done? Since this cannot be proven?

Comment: Its false so just set $n=1$, show they are not equal, and move on.

Comment: Start at i=2 and find out the power you need to put on the 3.